# How can i set global breakpoint using windbg

Tags: windows, windbg

Can i set global breakpoint, using windbg, like softice (for example: bpx MessageBoxA) so it will break on all user mode running apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 95/98/ME, the main system libraries like kernel32 and user32 are shared by all processes. A normal usermode debugger cannot set breakpoints at all on these libraries on these systems.

On Windows NT based systems each process has its own copy and if you set a software breakpoint the modified page will not affect other processes.

If you want to debug a process and its children, you can do this with WinDbg. A script could probably set the breakpoint for each new process.

If you want to catch it in all processes for some insane reason you could maybe use a kernel debugger and a processor breakpoint `ba`?

If MessageBox is the actual thing you want to capture, you could probably use `SetWinEventHook` or a CBT hook instead of a debugger...